# loopback query based related model

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback, angular-loopback

let's say I have Order model that hasMany Product(product_id, name, order_id) and Product belongs to Order

I want to find only those orders that have product with specific product_id.

According to https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Include-filter.html
this should work, but it doesn't

```
getOrders?filter={"include":{"relation":"Product","scope":{"where":{"product_id":"6"}}}}
```

that kid of filter shows  all orders  no matter if it has product with id 6 or not.

where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your query should show you all orders, but it will include only products that id fits your requirements. But it may depend on db connector you're using. Based on what you've wrote I guess it's mongo, so it's not possible.

Instead, you could turn around the query and look for products where product_id is 6 and include order relation. So the query would look like this:

```
getProducts?filter={"where": {"product_id": 6}, "include": "orders"}
```